# New object with parameters pulls nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, object, parameters, nullpointerexception

I am currently working with `Libgdx` for `Android` and `Desktop` development and I ran into some trouble. (nothing specific with `Libgdx`). This is just a user error (aka I've been trying to fix this for 2 hours now and I'm completely stumped). So this is whats up: I created a class so I can simply use a string to load a `Texture` (to use as a spritesheet)

```
public class Animator{

private int    FRAME_Y;     
private int    FRAME_X;     

private Animation           walk_down, walk_left, walk_right, walk_up, walk_spin;
private Animation MainAnimation;      
private static Texture             Sheet;      
static TextureRegion[]         walkRegion_down, walkRegion_left, walkRegion_right, walkRegion_up, walkRegion_spin;     
private SpriteBatch         spriteBatch;        
static TextureRegion           currentFrame;       

static float stateTime;   
private TextureRegion test;
private TextureRegion MainRegion;

public Animator(String location, int Y, int X, boolean flipped) {
    this.FRAME_Y = Y;
    this.FRAME_X = X;
    Sheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(location));

    int frameWidth = Sheet.getWidth() / FRAME_Y;
    int frameHeight = Sheet.getHeight() / FRAME_X;


    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(Sheet, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    MainRegion = new TextureRegion(Sheet, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    MainAnimation = new Animation(0.2f, MainRegion, MainRegion);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();                
    stateTime = 0f;
    return;
}

public static void render(Animator G, float x, float y) {
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch1 = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);                        
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    currentFrame = G.MainAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);  

    spriteBatch1.begin();
    spriteBatch1.draw(currentFrame, x, y);       
    spriteBatch1.end();
}}
```

Both of the funcitons are being used in this class /  /  / to create new Objects

```
public class LetSurviveMain extends Game{

//public static Entity player1;
public static Animator test, test2;
@Override
public void create () {

    //Map = new TmxMapLoader().load("Tutorial.tmx");
    //GameStart.show();
    Animator test = new Animator("Animations/test.png", 4, 4, false);
    Animator test2 = new Animator("Animations/test2.png", 4, 4, false);
}



@Override
public void render () {
    //GameStart.render();
    Animator.render(test, 150, 150);
    Animator.render(test2, 250, 200);
}}
```

The exact console error is:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.tlog.evil.Animator.render(Animator.java:71)
>       at com.tlog.evil.LetSurviveMain.render(LetSurviveMain.java:24)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

And it points to line 71 in my `Animator` class, which is this:

```
  currentFrame = G.MainAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
```

As I knew it would be an easy fix (just me over thinking it) Here is what I did:
Just removed the `Animator` In front of the assignement, as I already created one in the class. (the render method was referring to something that was never set.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your `Animator G` seems to be null

Comment: @SimonMarquis Wow, I guess this is what happens when I stay up too late. Thanks xD   Now I just seem to be stuck with a rendering issue (its only rendering one animation) Which, I always seem to fix these.